# _TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String')

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter and encountered this error. the app started to install but during the instalation this error will show "_TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String')"
[image]

```
        Future<Map> getParsedReverseGeocoding(LatLng latLng) async {
      var response =
          json.decode(await getReverseGeocodingGivenLatLngUsingMapbox(latLng));
      Map feature = response['features'][0];
      Map revGeocode = {
        'name': feature['text'],
        'address': feature['place_name'].split('${feature['text']}, ')[1],
        'place': feature['place_name'],
        'location': latLng
      };
      return revGeocode;
    }


        Future getReverseGeocodingGivenLatLngUsingMapbox(LatLng latLng) async {
      String query = '${latLng.longitude},${latLng.latitude}';
      String url = '$baseUrl/$query.json?access_token=$accessToken';
      url = Uri.parse(url).toString();
      print(url);
      try {
        _dio.options.contentType = Headers.jsonContentType;
        final responseData = await _dio.get(url);
        return responseData.data;
      } catch (e) {
        final errorMessage = DioExceptions.fromDioError(e as DioError).toString();
        debugPrint(errorMessage);
      }
    }
```

Comment: In which line does the error occure?

Comment: on the var response part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you set the content type to `Headers.jsonContentType` (which is the default I think) the decoding is done by `dio`. Simply remove `json.decode`:

```
var response = await getReverseGeocodingGivenLatLngUsingMapbox(latLng);
```